# Nano colors spaces and tabs

Tags: editor, nano

When I use nano to edit my C file it shows all of the spaces or tabs in green coloring.  I thought this may have been an issue with "whitespace display" and tried enabling and disabling it but it didnt work.  I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling nano and that didnt work either.

Any ideas on what this could be and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have solarized or another color scheme enabled in the terminal/emulator?

Comment: I changed the default background from system to black.  It seems to be some setting in nano.

Answer (score 18):

I just discovered the cause of this.  By default in the `/usr/share/c.nanorc` file "Trailing Whitespace" is turned on all the time.  This was annoying to me so I commented it out, `##`, do stop it from appearing.

Comment: On my system, the config file was located at `/usr/share/nano/c.nanorc`.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> -> Help

there is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> -> Color syntax highlighting enable/disable

Helps for me. Also many other cool features!